# How can I assign this pointer to my Iterator class

Tags: c++, iterator

Having class :

```
    template<class T>
    class Link
    {
        Link* myParent_;
        Link* myLeft_;
        Link* myRight_;
        T* myData_;
        void assign_(Link<T>*& marker, Link<T>*& aLink);
        void insert_(const T&);//inserts new data into a link
        void insert_(const T*);
        void remove_();//removes data from a link
    public:

        class Iterator : public iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, Link<T>*>
        {
        private:
            Link<T>* myData_;//How can I assign object of external class to this link? Rest of the Q below.
        public:
            Iterator();
            Iterator& left()const;
            Iterator& right()const;
            Iterator& top()const; 
        };
};
```

What I mean by that is how can I assign "this" object to myData_ and not myLeft_, myRight_ or myParent_ of "this" object?

I tried something like this:

```
template<class T>
Link<T>* Link<T>::me() const
{
    return const_cast<Link<T>*>(this);
}
```

and in Iterator:

```
template<class T>
Link<T>::Iterator::Iterator():myData_(nullptr)
{
    myData_ = me();//call from external class to me();
}
```

but I'm getting an error:

**Error 1   error C2352: 'Link::me' : illegal call of non-static member function**

Thank you.

Comment: Please make the title meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either via constructor:

```
Iterator(Link<T> *l) : myData_(l)  {}
```

Or via a setter and getter:

```
void setData(Link<T> *d)  { myData_ = d; }
Link<T>* getData() const { return myData_; }
```

Comment: Get/Set(er) are a code smell. The interface to your class should be actions that can be performed on the object not an interface that allows you to muck with the underlying data structures.